# Replace extra spaces in string with a single space in Java, without regex

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I want to basically to do this:

```
String secondString = firstString.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

Or replace all the multiple spaces in my string, with just a single space. However, is it possibly to do this without regex like I am doing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Java has a replace() method for strings that will find a given string and replace it with another string.  Generally, we expect you to at least make a try at programming something before asking a question . . . then we will make suggestions from there.

Answer (score 1):

> However, is it possibly to do this without regex like I am doing here?

**Yes**. The *regular expression* is clear and easy to read, so I would probably use that; but you ***could*** use a nested loop, a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [`Character.isWhitespace(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-) like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < firstString.length(); i++) {
    sb.append(firstString.charAt(i));
    if (Character.isWhitespace(firstString.charAt(i))) {
        // The current character is white space, skip characters until 
        // the next character is not.
        while (i + 1 < firstString.length() 
                    && Character.isWhitespace(firstString.charAt(i + 1))) {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
String secondString = sb.toString();
```

Note: This is a rare example of a nested loop that is O(N); the inner loop modifies the same counter as the outer loop.